# Issues in navigation in ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

i am creating hybrid app. i tried to navigate login page to home page but problem i faced is that my home page is overlapping on login page means that when my home page was opened and in back my login page display.

for navigation i used

```
this.navController.push(HomePage);
```

homepage.html

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of pages" (click)="itemSelected(item.title)">
    <ion-avatar item-left>
      <img src="{{item.image}}">
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Could we see more of your javascript/typescript code to help elaborate more?

Comment: You could aslo try to use `*ngIf="isLoggedIn"` in your html code to hide the login page, and show the homepage, vice-versa.

Comment: thank you for your replay..problem solved

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer :) I appreciate it you accept it as the correct answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `*ngIf="isLoggedIn"` in your html code to hide the login page, and show the homepage, vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this solution

```
this.navController.push(HomePage);
```